# are methods that modify input parameters and return them bad?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public class MyClass
{
        ....
}

public static MyClass MyClassModifier(MyClass myinstance)
{

  ......
 return myinstance;
}
```

It seems to me that returning myinstance doesn't actually do anything here, in other words this, achieves the same as the code above (As long as myinstance is not assigned to another object in the method):

```
public static void MyClassModifier(MyClass myinstance)
{

  ......

}
```

I could, of course, do this:

```
public static MyClass MyClassModifier(MyClass myinstance)
{

  ......
  return new MyClass();
}
```

but this seems pretty clunky and if the constructor for MyClass has many parameters then this becomes really clunky, so, the question is then, which one is preferable and why?

From a functional programming point of view it seems that the last one is the way to go but I'm not sure that this is the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> are methods that modify input parameters and return them bad?

Yes. They're misleading - the client will assume your method reads the input parameter, creates a new object and returns it. When in fact, that's not what's going on. The returned value *is* the input value, and there's no need for the client to capture it.

Regarding your second question, whether you should mutate the input value or create a new one, the answer highly depends on what you're trying to achieve. It's impossible to give you a better answer without any context.

> From a functional programming point of view it seems that the last one is the way to go but I'm not sure that this is the best way.

Yes, in functional programming you want immutable state - which means `MyClass` cannot be modified, and so you have to return a new instance of it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this is pretty much what I imagined.

Regarding mutating the input value vs creating a new one, the example I actually had in mind, consisted of a List as an input value